An error is reported when installing the Python PaddleHub package
When I try to install paddlehub package in python I meet this error.
And my python version is python3.12
pip version is newest.
The error below
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for onnx (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [23 lines of output]
      致命错误：不是 git 仓库（或者任何父目录）：.git
      /private/var/folders/wy/0bd32d55105_hq0p2h7m0_600000gn/T/pip-build-env-u_lkh47g/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:476: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: Invalid dash-separated options
      !!
      
              ********************************************************************************
              Usage of dash-separated 'license-file' will not be supported in future
              versions. Please use the underscore name 'license_file' instead.
      
              By 2024-Sep-26, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
              or your builds will no longer be supported.
      
              See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
              ********************************************************************************
      
      !!
        opt = self.warn_dash_deprecation(opt, section)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      running create_version
      running cmake_build
      Using cmake args: ['/Users/baijiale/Documents/Code/py/aistudio/paddlehub/bin/cmake', '-DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.2_1/bin/python3.12', '-DBUILD_ONNX_PYTHON=ON', '-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON', '-DONNX_NAMESPACE=onnx', '-DPY_EXT_SUFFIX=.cpython-312-darwin.so', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-DONNX_ML=1', '/private/var/folders/wy/0bd32d55105_hq0p2h7m0_600000gn/T/pip-install-xtn0w45p/onnx_c911237e4c5c43df8fc7060b2502c134']
      error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/baijiale/Documents/Code/py/aistudio/paddlehub/bin/cmake'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for onnx
Failed to build onnx
ERROR: Could not build wheels for onnx, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I want to solve this problem and install the paddlehub package successfully

By the way, I use venv create a virtual envirenment. And in MacOS 14
